# Azure Websites Allowed APIs

Tags: api, azure

I understand that Azure Websites are full trust, (which is fantastic ) and that it uses some kind of 'new' virtualization technology that prevents using certain win32 APIs as reported in other threads here.

My question is this: Which APIs or subsystems are allowed? Our particular issue is using GDI to extract font data, it works fine as web role, but not as website. Is there a guide to what operations are allowed on azure websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some high level information on [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment). As you point out, GDI is probably the main thing that is not supported.

If you run into something else that doesn't work and doesn't seem to be related to GDI, please let us know

Answer (score 1):

With Azure Websites, your app is running in a sandbox. I believe below is the only detail documentation we had.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

if you are experience particular issue with our sandbox, you can report thru Kudu github issue and we will pass your opinion to our platform team.